# Determinant of 2x2 matrix divided by the difference between the first row

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, determinant

I've inherited some old source code that contains this matrix operation and I'm not really sure what it is doing.
There are two vectors, shown in the diagram as red and blue $[x;y]$.
$$
r = [-184929 ; 431070] 
\quad \text{and} \quad 
b = [222871; 438373]. 
$$

These are combined into a $2 \times 2$ matrix and the determinant is calculated which I know will give the area of the parallelogram. *But then this is divided by $x_2 - x_1$*. So I end up with
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-184929 & 222871\\
431070 & 438373
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\frac{x_2 \, y_1 - x_1 \, y_2}{x_2-x_1}
$$

The determinant in this case ${}\approx 1.77 \times 10^{11}$, and then when dividing by $x_2-x_1$ I get ${}\approx 434381$. In the context of the application I'm working on it would seem appropriate to calculate the average of the red and blue vectors, which if I do that I end up with $[189710; 434721]$. The average value of $434721$ is close to the $434381$, but I'm just curious to know generally what taking the determinant and dividing by the e.g. $(x_2 - x_1)$ does. I just haven't seen it before. Thanks for any explanation.

[image: vectors]

Comment: I would really suspect here that this has a contextual meaning, that is, a meaning for that specific application the code was developed for.

Comment: The line through the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ intersects the y-axis at $y=\frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_2-x_1}.$ Maybe it is somehow related to this?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, that is it! I was over thinking this, thank you for pointing that out! If you want to post an answer I will mark it as answered Thank You!KBS you are correct, this is application specific and if I were to spend time describing the larger application this probably would have been obvious. Thank you both for commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line through the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ intersects the $y$-axis at $y=\frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_2-x_1}.$

This can be seen as follows:

The general equation of a line through the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ is
$$
\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
y &=& \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\, x - \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\, x_1 + y_1 \\
&=&\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\, x + \frac{-(y_2-y_1)x_1 + (x_2-x_1)y_1}{x_2-x_1} \\
&=&\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\, x + \frac{-x_1y_2+y_1x_1 + x_2y_1-x_1y_1}{x_2-x_1} \\
&=&\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\, x + \frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_2-x_1}
\end{eqnarray}